# American vs British use of "the" in “after (the) summer break was over”

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

Which one is the correct one? Or do they depend if we're using American/British English?

A: She went there after **the** summer break was over.

or

B: She went there after summer break was over.

A British friend says A is the correct one; an American friend says B is the correct one. And I'm left wondering which one is the correct one...

Comment: They are both correct.

Comment: *And I'm left wondering which one is the correct one...* Here is the solution -> If you travel to the UK use 1, if you travel to the US, use 2.

Comment: After winter ended. After the winter ended. Same thing.

Comment: Stephen Fry said : Many authors write much better books in faulty english than brilliant scholars who write perfect english... Yeah like soon after holiday or after the holiday? after soon after lunch or after the lunch? It's not worth chasing after the extremities of grammatical perfection.

Comment: There is absolutely no BrE/AmE thing happening here with the and the null. Except maybe the word break in summer break. Change break to holiday and you get the same thing. Either one.

Comment: summer break sounds more slangy

Comment: This reminds me of American "I was in the hospital" vs English, "I was in hospital."

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think "summer **break**" is [essentially American,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20summer%20break%2Cfor%20the%20summer%20break%2Cfor%20summer%20holidays%2Cfor%20the%20summer%20holidays&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) and it ***wouldn't*** normally have an article in the cited example (but it's certainly not "incorrect" to include it).

The [standard British equivalent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20summer%20break%2Cfor%20the%20summer%20break%2Cfor%20summer%20holidays%2Cfor%20the%20summer%20holidays&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) is "**the** summer **holidays**", which ***must*** have an article if used in the cited example context.

Comment: summer break may be American but so what? The point is: after the summer ended versus after summer ended. That is the grammar point to be addressed: the and null set. No one asked about the differences. You could use any event thing.

Comment: No. There's a major US/UK usage split here - especially to do with *school* holidays.

Comment: @Lambie the head noun of the phrase is not "summer" but "break"; the question isn't about "the summer" vs. "summer" but about "the break" vs. "break."  Your example is a complete sentence in which "ended" is a verb, not part of a noun phrase that includes the word "summer." While I (American) don't find "the summer break" to be all that odd, I can't say the same for "the spring break."

Comment: @phoog: [This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+spring+break%2Cfor+the+spring+break&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) confirms that your and your compatriots' aversion to the article is definitely even stronger with ***spring** break*. The British equivalent there is [***the** Easter holidays*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+easter+holidays%2Cfor+the+easter+holidays&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) - almost always ***plural, with article***.

Comment: @phoog I am saying it is the same thing. summer break, Easter break, winter vacation, summer vacation. Those can all be both.

Comment: @Lambie - but they aren't. They are overwhelmingly one way in the UK and another in the US. Here in the UK we would also never use "summer vacation" or "winter vacation." phoog and FumbleFingers have it correct.

Comment: @Lambie "The summer holidays" in American English would refer to "the holidays that occur in the summer," i.e. the Fourth of July, Labor Day, etc. (At least, that's how I would read it.)

Comment: @alphabet: That's probably a "generational" thing (your *parents* may be more familiar with the usage still retained in British English). The first link in my answer strongly implies that ***the summer holidays*** was commonly used in AmE until 2-3 decades ago with the "school holidays" sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was in school in the US from 4-3 decades ago (78-97) and we *never* said "holidays" in the British sense. Maybe it was 4-5 or 5-6 decades ago? I don’t recall ever hearing "summer break" either. There was "winter break" which could have been called "the holidays" as in "happy holidays", "spring break", and "summer *vacation*".

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks for the well-thought reply. I also got to know that summer break isn't very used in the UK, and perhaps summer vacation would be a better choice overall, for both my american and british friends!

Comment: @Doubter: You'll *probably* be understood by Brits if you use ***summer vacation***. That's with or without the article - just because we *always* use it with our ***summer holidays*** when we mean the entire period when schools are closed doesn't mean we expect Americans to do the same. But it's not "standard" BrE. Note that a site-specific search for ***the summer vacation*** gets just 250 hits on *The Guardian* (British newspaper) website, but ***the summer holidays*** gets over three and a half *thousand* hits.

Comment: Glancing at some instances of ***the summer vacation*** in *The Guardian*, I have the strong impression that particular "less common" variant is far more likely to be used in the context of *universities, lecturers*, and *undergraduates*, where ***the summer holidays*** more often refers to when ***schools*** are closed.

Comment: @RoryAlsop OMG. I am saying that whether you say summer holiday or summer break, it's the same thing in both countries. Of course, vacation is not used in the UK as it is used in the US,  and holiday(s) is preferred. How to make the most of the summer break
AuthorDaniel Higginbotham, EditorPostedJuly, 2021, a UK text: https://www.prospects.ac.uk/applying-for-university/university-life/how-to-make-the-most-of-the-summer-break

Comment: (American English) I personally treat the noun phrase "summer break" the same way I would "Wednesday" or "December", for generally the same reasons.

Comment: FYI, as a life-long US person, I'd write the article in the sentence given, but consider it optional if the sentence ended at "summer break." without the "was over" tacked onto the end.

Comment: @Lambie I think the point of this answer is that the usage ot 'the' is more a matter of collocation rather than grammar. And collocation is a matter of usage. So it's not unreasonable to consider the other words involved in the collocation.

Answer (score 28):

They are both correct, though each is more common in a different region.

My understanding is that AmE treats "summer break" as an abstract, as it's the name of a period that happens every year. In this interpretation, "summer break" is a general concept, it's not just a specific break during the summer of a specific year.

Therefore, it is treated the same way as other abstract nouns and it receives no article. Other examples include:

> **Love** is all around us.
> I wash myself using **water**.
> **Detail** is not something I concern myself with.

All of these nouns refer to general concepts, not concrete instances, hence why they're abstract.

"The summer break" is more common in BrE, and it tends to refer to a specific break during a specific summer (which is usually contextually obvious).

This makes it a concrete noun, which does receive an article. Note that I am using the same nouns as before in this example, but their meaning has slightly shifted from before.

> **The love** I get from my family is amazing.
> I dipped my toes in **the water**.
> Just look at **the details** in this painting, it's breathtaking.

This is talking about specific instances, not general concepts. The specific instance of love from my family (not all love), the specific body of water (not all water), the specific details in this painting (not any unspecified details).

---

Theoretically, you'd be talking about *every* summer break when you omitted the article, since you're referring to the abstract concept. However, casual speech is not as strict about rules, and it's generally understood that even though it may be used as an abstract noun, it can make sense to only refer to the summer break which is contextually relevant.

Comment: This construction is used with many time points/periods: "I'll visit after summer break / summer / Christmas / March"--all of those are readily understood to refer to the relevant, upcoming one.  That usage is so common that to me trying to use it in the abstract comes off as awkward and unclear.  If I heard "I visit grandma after Christmas," I'd have to stop and clarify what the speaker meant.

Comment: @GrandOpener ... I question your example sentence as well... I you referring to "the grandma", or "the Christmas", or "the visit"? (yes, I know my commas and question mark belong inside the quotes). and yes, I know you mean _next_ Christmas, and _my_ grandma and _will_ visit.

Comment: I suspect that AmE treats "summer break" as uncountable because *summer* is uncountable. Of course, "summer" is actually modifying "break," and "break" is usually countable, so BrE is more logical here.

Comment: @alphabet I'm not quite convinced that summer is uncountable. E.g. _"How many summers have we spent together in Barbados?"_

Comment: @Flater I should say: summer is uncountable *in some contexts*, e.g. "Summer is my favorite time of year."

Comment: @alphabet If I'm not mistaken, "break" is similarly uncountable in similar contexts, e.g. "I do not answer my work phone while I'm on break."

Answer (score 10):

A complement to [user FumbleFingers' answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/601922/349876)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think maybe [this AmE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+summer+break%2Cfor+the+summer+break%2Cfor+summer+holidays%2Cfor+the+summer+holidays&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) and [this BrE chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+summer+break%2Cfor+the+summer+break%2Cfor+summer+holidays%2Cfor+the+summer+holidays&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) summarize the situation better. They clearly show that "break" is a recent Americanism not much used by Brits. But Americans still use "holidays" **a lot**.

Comment: AE calls it vacation. The *summer* vacation, or *Summer* vacation.

Comment: An ngram shows that "vacation" is used much more often, that's right. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=summer+vacation%2Csummer+holiday&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: But [*with AND without the article*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+summer+vacation%2Cfor+summer+holiday%2Cfor+summer+holidays%2Cfor+the+summer+vacation%2Cfor+the+summer+holidays&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10), *for [the] **summer holidays*** are the two most common versions in BrE. Usually *with* the article is the extended *school* holidays, whereas with no article it's often just a week or two off work spent away at a resort.

Comment: @Lambie An ngram search will tell you that if you take the time to examine all the hits from that research, but it'll be a while before you get to such a conclusion.

Comment: You have to be able to spell out the difference in an answer in your own words or quoting someone.  A bunch of ngrams does not cut the mustard.

Comment: @pipe There is no need to make more of it than it is; it is called a complement to another answer, and as such not pretending to be too much of an answer;  it is nonetheless  the source of an idea that has been used to provide more data for the first answer. If you deem this type of complement of little value, then abstain from upvoting, that's perfectly all right. However, do not downvote it, there is nothing wrong in it.

Comment: @pipe furthermore, the reasons given for banning answers created by AI do not apply to an answer that comprises a set of graphs chosen by a person.  If LPH generated this answer by asking HAL 9000 to supply some ngrams in response to this question or to complement FumbleFingers's answer, that would be another matter.

Comment: As a girl I was used to hearing "summer holidays" even when the meaning was *not* plural… Not sure if BrEng corpus will reflect this usage.

Comment: It does! https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+summer+holidays%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cthe+summer+holiday%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Cthe+summer+break%3Aeng_us_2019%2Csummer+break%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-fiction-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Mari-LouA do you know many academic calendars in which there is only one day off during the summer?

Comment: @phoog  I'm sorry I don't understand. Do Americans say  *summer vacations*  because there is more than one day off in the summer? Look at LPH ngram, they used *summer holiday* which appears to be singular. Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was talking about "holidays," not "vacations," and implicitly wondering whether the origins of "holiday" in "holy day" led to "holidays" being preferred for any period of two days or more, or perhaps any period that contains two or more holidays even if some of the days falling in that period are not holidays.  And I was talking about Britain because you said "Not sure if BrEng corpus will reflect this usage," so I thought your "as a girl" implied "in Britain."

Comment: @phoog you said all of the above in that one line? `do you know many academic calendars in which there is only one day off during the summer?` I was thinking quite simply of "…one holiday, I've had two holidays" as in "…one break/vacation, I've had two breaks/vacations“ etc.  so  I was concerned that you were being sarcastic. Oops!

Comment: @FumbleFingers When Americans use the term "Holidays", it usually refers to specific days, like Christmas, Easter, New Years, Halloween, etc.  You won't see "Summer Holidays" in the US because summer is a relatively long period without any major holidays here.  (Basically nothing from the 4th of July until Labor Day in September.)  When we say "Holidays" it's usually referring to the Thanksgiving-through-New Years period in the winter (Nov-Jan) where there's a higher concentration of them.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman How do you explain this ngram then: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=summer+holidays%2Csummer+break%2Csummer+holiday&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3?

Comment: Whenn I search for the *three* variants most likely to refer to the extended "no school" period in summer -  [***children in the summer holidays,children in the summer break,children in summer break***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=children+in+the+summer+holidays%2Cchildren+in+the+summer+break%2Cchildren+in+summer+break&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), only the first version generates graphable results. And they're nearly ***all*** from the BrE corpus - searching the AmE corpus returns nothing at all!

Comment: @LPH Borrowing from UK usage maybe?  Though I'm talking more in the general sense of "holidays" without a season specified.  If you say, e.g. "Home for the holidays", you're talking about winter, not summer.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Something might be wrong with the research engine: a very quick perusal showed  3 books concerned with Great Britain and quite a few with  lands where the first language is not English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was certainly being sarcastic.  It was intended as a (good-natured) jab at the many ways in which "summer holidays" could mean something "not plural" or plural, and the (absurd) possibility that each of the dozens of days between terms might be counted as a separate "holiday."

Comment: @LPH also books by Australian and Canadian authors, modern reprints of 19th-century works, and some self-published books where the nationality of the author was not immediately apparent.  But I certainly didn't see any obviously US author using the phrase "summer holidays" after the second world war.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this question is about whether it is correct to prefix "summer break" with "the" or not.

In my experience (raised in Scotland, lived in many places), the rest of the UK (particularly South-East England) leave "the" out, while in Scotland it is left in.

This seems to be the general pattern, not just for "the" for example:

- In Scotland: "I'm going to my bed" (most likely "I'm away to my bed")
- In Rest of UK: "I'm going to bed"

- Scotland: "I'm just back from my work"
- UK: "I'm just back from work"

etc.

Comment: This is interesting and informative but is not an answer to the original question so would be better left as a comment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi JSwan, welcome to ELU! The question is about American vs British English, though.

Comment: The question is indeed about American vs British English.

But what is "British English"?

As someone who was born and brought up in "Great Britain", I can see clearly the subtleties in the question.

There are four countries in the "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland".

I supplied a detailed and honest answer. From my first hand experience. Offered without prejudice or expectation of reward.

If you want to delete it, do as you wish.

Life is not a code review.